# Unable to load game.html after clicking on the buttons

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

Why am I not being directed to game.html after clicking on the buttons?
The
file Structure is server/server.js, public/index.html,public/game.html.
index.html

```
 < !DOCTYPE html>

 <html>

 <title>QUIZ GAME</title>


  <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

 <body>

 <!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->

<div class="w3-top">

<div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-wide w3-padding w3-card">

<a href="#home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><b>QUIZ</b>Book</a>

<!-- Float links to the right. Hide them on small screens -->

<div class="w3-right w3-hide-small">
  
<a href="#projects" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CATEGORIES</a>
  
<a href="#about" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">About</a>
  
<a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Contact</a>

</div>

</div>

</div>

 <!-- Header -->


 <header class="w3-display-container w3-content w3-wide" style="max-

  width:1500px;" id="home">

 <img class="w3-image" src="pics/quiz.jpg" alt="Architecture" width="1500" 

 height="800">

 <div class="w3-display-middle w3-margin-top w3-center">

 <h1 class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-white"><span class="w3-padding w3-black w3-

  opacity-min"><b>QUIZ</b></span> <span class="w3-hide-small w3-text-light-

  grey">Book</span></h1>


</div>

</header>

 <!-- Page content -->

 <div class="w3-content w3-padding" style="max-width:1564px">

 <!-- Project Section -->

 <div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" id="projects">

 <h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-

 16">CATEGORIES</h3>

 </div>

 <div class="w3-row-padding">

 <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
  
 <div class="w3-display-container">
    
  <button class="w3-button w3-hover-black" ><img src="pics/GK.jpg" 
   
  alt="House" style="width:100%"><div class="content">
        
  <h3>GENERAL KNOWLEDGE</h3></div></button>
    
  </div>
  
 </div>
   
 <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
 
 <div class="w3-display-container">
    
   <button class="w3-button w3-hover-black"><img src="pics/maths_school.jpg" 


 alt="House" style="width:100%"> </button>
    
  </div>

 </div>

 <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">

  <div class="w3-display-container">

    <button class="w3-button w3-hover-black"><img src="pics/bollywood.jpg" 

  alt="House" style="width:100%"> </button>

    

  </div>

</div>

<div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">

  <div class="w3-display-container">

        <button class="w3-button w3-hover-black"><img 
 
    src="pics/hollywood.jpg" alt="House" style="width:100%"> </button>

    

  </div>

 </div>

 </div>



<div class="w3-row-padding">

 <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">

  <div class="w3-display-container">

        <button class="w3-button w3-hover-black"><img src="pics/cricket.jpg" 

       alt="House" style="width:99%"> </button>

    
  </div>
  
 </div>

 <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
  
 <div class="w3-display-container">
        
  <button class="w3-button w3-hover-black"> <img src="pics/football.jpg" 
   
  alt="House" style="width:99%"></button>
    
  </div>

 </div>

 <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
  
 <div class="w3-display-container">
        
 <button class="w3-button w3-hover-black"> <img src="pics/sports.jpg" 
 
 alt="House" style="width:99%"> </button>
    
  </div>
  
 </div>
   
 <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
 
  <div class="w3-display-container">
        
 <button class="w3-button w3-hover-black"> <img src="pics/science.png" 
  
alt="House" style="width:99%"> </button>
    
  </div>

</div>

<div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
  
 <div class="w3-display-container">
       
  <button class="w3-button w3-hover-black"><img src="pics/history.jpg" 

  alt="House" style="width:99%"> </button>
    
  </div>

  </div>

  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
  
  <div class="w3-display-container">
        
  <button class="w3-button w3-hover-black"> <img src="pics/music.png" 
 
  alt="House" style="width:99%"> </button>
   
  </div>

 </div>

 <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
 
 <div class="w3-display-container">
        
  <button class="w3-button w3-hover-black">  <img src="pics/tennis.jpg" 
  
 alt="House" style="width:99%"> </button>
   
  </div>

 </div>

 </div>


 <!-- About Section -->

<div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" id="about">

<h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-16">About</h3>
    
</div>



 <!-- Contact Section -->

 <div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" id="contact">

 <h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-
 
 16">Contact</h3>

 <p>Lets get in touch and talk about your and our next project.</p>

 <form action="/" target="_blank">

  <input class="w3-input" type="text" placeholder="Name" required 
 
 name="Name">

 <input class="w3-input w3-section" type="text" placeholder="Email" required 
  
name="Email">

 <input class="w3-input w3-section" type="text" placeholder="Subject" 

required name="Subject">

  <input class="w3-input w3-section" type="text" placeholder="Comment" 
 
 required name="Comment">
  
 <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-section" type="submit">
    
   <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> SEND MESSAGE
    
</button>
```

```
<script>
  
document.getElementsByClassName('w3-button w3-hover-black').onclick = 

function(){

    window.location.href = "https://localhost:3000/game.html";
    
}
```

```
</html>



 in game.html
  
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<title>QUIZ book</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id = "gameDiv"></div>
     
 <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    
 <script src = "lib/phaser.min.js"></script>
    
  <script src = "main.js"></script>
     
 <script src = "player.js"></script>

 </body>
   
</html>


in server/server.js

var express = require('express');

 var socketIo = require('socket.io');

var path = require('path');

var http = require('http');

var app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT ||3000 ;

const pathjoin = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
 
 const pathjoin1 = path.join(__dirname,'../public/game.html');

 var server = http.createServer(app);

 app.use(express.static(pathjoin));

 app.use('/game.html',express.static(pathjoin1));

 var io = socketIo(server);

 io.on('connection',(socket)=>{

 console.log('user connected ' + socket.id);

  });





server.listen(port,()=>{

console.log('server started');

});
```

Comment: Please provide a complete error message. The exact code that is causing the error message and perhaps it would be nice to add an actual question too.

Comment: there is no error being shown actually. .its just that when i click on the buttons i am not being directed to game/html. Maybe i dont know the implementation! help me!

Comment: You post the whole page because you have problem with 1 button. Just make a small example in https://jsfiddle.net/ that shows us the problem. Add only the needed javascipt/css/html that is involved in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array so you have to go through it or use jQuery, as an example:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('w3-button w3-hover-black'); 
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      window.location.href = "https://localhost:3000/game.html";
   });
}
```

Comment: My apologies for the way i asked. Well, I am being directed to game.html after clicking on the buttons but after being directed to localhost:3000/game.html it doesn't load the page ;it says :This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response

Comment: @rohan tell me about your server, and check http too? unless your server support https, I didn't down vote but I think the problem was with your way of asking, (just so u know) ...

Comment: doesnt work even after editing it to http! It is an express server. You can have a look the server/server.js code in my post.

Comment: whats the response this time?

Comment: no response much to my dismay! it shows the same thing : localhost sent an invalid response.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is `getElementSbyClassName` return array of all elements who have this class name, for example to have OnClick function on first element :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('w3-button w3-hover-black')[0].onclick =
```

you will have to iterate over them and attach a handler to each like this :

```
var elts = getElementsByClassName('w3-button w3-hover-black');
for( var i=0,il = elts.length; i< il; i ++ ){
 elts[i].onclick = 

function(){
//your code..
}
```

Comment: i know ^^ i ask to the person who downvote if he looks this

Comment: @LeoR. I had some like this too. can it be because of the way he did ask? and we have to tell him???

Comment: well, i am being directed to game.html after clicking on the buttons but after being directed to https://localhost:3000/game.html it doesn't load the page ;it says :This site can’t provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.